# Version Control Foreman / Puppet

Tags: git, puppet

I have just setup Foreman for the first time & am not sure how to go about putting all of my configurations under version control. I know I can use Git for each module I install on my Puppet master but would prefer a more holistic solution that encompasses not just modules but also what classes are associated with each host and any variables set on the hosts. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated along with related workflows. In case it's relevant, I do have GitLab setup as a central Git server on site and plan to setup a CI server such as Jenkins soon.

Answer (score 1):

Use Roles, Profiles and Hiera to manage different configurations, with mixed modules. Check this intro from PuppetLabs: http://puppetlabs.com/presentations/designing-puppet-rolesprofiles-pattern.

In Foreman, you can group hosts by organisations, environments and groups. I'm not sure how to version control Foreman's configuration though. Foreman uses a DB server for its settings.

Create packages for all modules, and for Hiera, based on Foreman hierarchy.